# Skyrim switching between followers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I had this one follower, Marcurio and then I saw Lydia and thought I'd give her a try. I released Marcurio and he wandered off in his full daedric armor... oops

Can you get a follower back after releasing them? If yes, will they be at their original hire location? And will they cost money again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you get a follower back after releasing them?

Yes.

> If yes, will they be at their original hire location?

Yes. Marcurio's in The Bee and the Barb in Riften, by the way.

> And will they cost money again?

Maybe. Some cost nothing -- usually you have to do a quest to win their trust -- but others you will have to pay for again. Marcurio isn't one of them, but he *might* rejoin at no cost if dismissed only a short time ago. I don't know if that means right after you dismiss him or a few days/hours later, as my follower isn't a mercenary.

Comment: This is correct. He is at the Bee and Barb (where I originally hired him) and he has all his armor, although it's not equiped.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm correct, Marcurio should return to A: A house that you own or B: Where you hired him

You shouldn't have any trouble recovering your daedric set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may never find him for about a month in real time and you have to be skipping hours. After you do all this he will be back in the bee and the barb

Comment: Pa land skip hours and you will be fine an find h back in the bee and the barb